# Url to connect android to mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, wamp

I am trying to retrieve data from localhost database created using xampp mysql.

```
public class JASONUseActivity extends Activity {

    EditText byear; // To take birthyear as input from user
    Button submit;
    TextView tv; // TextView to show the result of MySQL query 

    String returnString; // to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
        .penaltyLog().build());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        byear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);

        // define the action when user clicks on submit button
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the name birth year and its value submitted by user   
                ArrayList < NameValuePair > postParameters = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();

                // define the parameter
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birthyear", byear.getText().toString()));
                String response = null;

                // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://localhost/jasonscript.php", postParameters);

                    // store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
                    String result = response.toString();
```

I am not able to view data in textview. Is the url correct??

Here is the jasonscript.php located in xampp/htdocs

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";

$db_uid = "root";

$db_pass = "";

$db_name = "";

$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_uid, $db_pass) or die('could not connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear > '" . $_POST["birthyear"] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $output[] = $row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

I have given internet permission in the manifest file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume there are no errors in Android? Can you confirm (it is possible you don't get a Force Close, because you have a try/catch ). If there is no error with Anrdoi - check you wamp server for errors - right click and go to apache - error log. Run your app and get the last lines from the log at that time if there are any errors.

Comment: Connect with the IP of the computer not localhost

Comment: No the app is not force closing. There were no errors in apache error log. I am getting strict mode error in logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `localhost` on your Android device you are reffering to a service on the device itself. Use the IP / hostname of your server to get the data.

Sidenote: Also take a look into `ASyncTask` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) because downloading data in onCreate will lock your UI-Thread (if it takes long) and can result in an `App Not Responding` or `Force Close`. Even if it doens't give a crash the user-expericience will be degraded because the app doesn't repond.

Comment: So, i should give "ipaddress/jasonscript.php OR "ipaddress/localhost/jasonscript.php    ?

Comment: `CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://api.mywebserver.com/jasonscript.php",postParameters);` OR `CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.0.2/jasonscript.php",postParameters);` with ofcourse your own IP adress

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` on the device refers to its loopback interface, **not** your development machine that is hosting the database you are trying to connect to. In order to have a virtual device connect to your development machine's loopback interface you need to use `10.0.2.2`. You could change your URL to something like this to hit your development machine:

```
CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/jasonscript.php", postParameters);
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592881/postgresql-not-connecting-to-android-using-jdbc-throwing-org-postgresql-util-psq/27593405#27593405) for more details regarding how the emulator's networking works.