# Postgresql not connecting to android using JDBC throwing org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I am developing an android application for which I need to connect to Postgresql database, I installed it 9.3 version, and checked in PGAdminIII it is connecting. I also created a java project in eclipse just for testing JDBC it is connecting successfully but when I am trying to connet to Postgresql from Android project it is throwing error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
 Here is the code Which I written in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

          Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
          Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.43.207:5432/testdb", "postgres", "password");
          System.out.println("connection success");
          conn.close() ;
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

and **pg_hba.conf**

## IPv4 local connections:

host     all     all     192.168.43.207  trust

## IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

**postgresql.conf**

listen_addresses = '*'

Note: If I am changing ip address 192.168.43.207 with localhost/127.0.0.1 it is throwing error-
    org.postgresql.util.psqlexception connection refused. check that the hostname and port are          correct
    I have googled about it and also seen posts on Stackoverflow but nothing works.
I am using **windows7** please provide solution according to it.
please help me as I am fighting it for last two days but nothing works.

Edit: when I run these commands from CMD in windows I got following outout

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc query postgresql-9.3

SERVICE_NAME: postgresql-9.3
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -a | findstr 5432
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           -PC:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5432              -PC:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:5432             -PC:49573       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:5432             -PC:49574       ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Can you ping to the curresponding IP for heartbeat checking ? and check service on port 5432 is running or not ?

Comment: I edited it for checking which service is running and I also pinged the IP from command prompt, it is sending packets 100%.

Comment: Seems all are perfect. Can you check the heartbeat of Android Device to the Physical System where the PostGreSQL reside ?

Comment: So, just to be clear, your Android device is trying to connect to `127.0.0.1`? Is your device a virtual device or a physical device?

Comment: I am using android SDK on eclipse which opens android emulator to test application.

Comment: @SK08 how to test heartbeat of android device emulator I don't know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `127.0.0.1` on the Android goes to the virtual Android device and not to your machine hosting the PostgreSQL database. Referencing the [Android emulator documentation for networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking):

> Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall
>   service that isolates it from your development machine's network
>   interfaces and settings and from the internet. An emulated device can
>   not see your development machine or other emulator instances on the
>   network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet
>   to a router/firewall.

And below that, there is a table for the virtual router:

[image: Android virtual router network]

And further down in a  section about using `127.0.0.1` (emphasis mine):

> Also note that the address 127.0.0.1 on your development machine
>   corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface. If you want to
>   access services running on your development machine's loopback
>   interface (a.k.a. 127.0.0.1 on your machine), **you should use the
>   special address 10.0.2.2 instead.**

You should use `10.0.2.2` rather than `127.0.0.1` if you want to connect to the development machine.